# Node vs Relationship

Tags: neo4j, schema, nodes, relationships

So I've just worked through the tutorial and I'm unclear about a few things. The main one, however, is how do you decide when something is a relationship and when it should be a Node?
For example, in the Movies Database,there is a relationship showing who acted in which film. A property of that relationship is the Role. BUT, what if it's a series of films? The role may well be constant between films (say, Jack Ryan in The Hunt for Red October, Patriot Games etc.)

We may also want to have some kind of Character bio, which would obviously remain constant between movies. Worse, the actor may change from one movie to another (Alec Baldwin then Harrison Ford.) There are many others like this (James Bond, for example).

Even if the actor doesn't change (Main roles in Harry Potter) the character is constant.  So, at what point would the Role become a node in its own right? When it does, can I have a 3-way relationship (Actor-Role-Movie)? Say I start of with it being a relationship and then, down the line, decide it should've been a node, is there a simple way to go through the database and convert it?

Answer (score 0):

**No there is no way to convert your datamodel.** When you start your own Database first take time to find a fitting schema. There is no ideal way to create a schema and also there are many different models fitting to the same situation without being totally wrong.

**My strategy** is to put less information to the relationship itself. I only add properties that directly concern the relationship and store all the other data in the nodes. Also think of properties you could use for traversing the graph. For example you might need some flags or even different labels for relationships even they more or less are the same. The `apoc.algo.aStar` is only including relationshiptypes you want (you could exclude certain nodes by giving them a special relationshiptype). So keep that in mind that you take a look at procedures that you might use later.

Try to create the schema as simple as possible and find a way to stay consistent in terms of what things are nodes and what deserves a relationship. Dont mix it up.

Choose a design that makes sense for you! `(device 1)-[cable]-(device 2)` vs `(device 1)-[has cable]-(cable)-[has cable]-(device 2)` in this case I'd prefer the first because `[has cable]` wouldn't  bring anymore information. Irrespective to what I wrote above I would have a lot of information in this `[cable]` relationship but it totally makes sense for me because I wouldnt want to search in a device node for cable information.

For your example giving the role a own node is also valid way. For example if you want to espacially query which actors had the same role in common I'll totally go for giving the role a extra node.

Summary: 
Think of what you want to do with the data and choose the easiest model.

Comment: "No there is no way to convert your datamodel." How sure are you of this? I believe there should be a way to do it, using APOC or export/import to CSV.